# Making Route on multiple marker Click google maps -javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have populated a google map with several markers. When the user clicks on a marker "B" I would like it to make a route between "A" & "B" & making "B" now as a Source & then when user clicks on "C" I would like it to make a route between "B" & "C". & so on !!

Thanks in advance !! working example would be appreciated !!

my working code

http://js.do/FahadMalik/56681

Answer (score 0):

These two links can get you started.They have working examples too.
The general idea is to have an array with your markers and their coordinates and each time you click on a  marker get its coordinates and the previous too and then do the calculations.

[Google Maps Direction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)

[Click Event Listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)